# How to pull a series of commits from another repository in git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull

I have two repositories, `A` and `B`. I want to copy all the files in `A`, with a subset of  their history, into `B`. `B` has its own files with history that I'd like to preserve, too; it is not a fresh, new repository.

You see, `A` has 28,000 commits. All but the most recent 30 or so, I don't care about. For simplicity of discussion, let's say that I'm not interested in commits #1 through #27,970, but I would like to retain the history for commits #27,971 through #28,000.

I've tried two different approaches.

- Squash commits #1 through #27,970 commits in `A` (using `git rebase -i`) into a single commit, and then `git pull` `A` into `B`. The trouble I ran into here as that during the rebase of `A`, there were a lot of errors about git being unable to apply certain commits. I'm not knowledgeable about these commits in `A`, so I was unable to fix them. (Plus, it was taking a *long* time to perform the rebase - many hours and I wasn't done yet.)
- Download a snapshot (i.e., no history) of `A` at commit #27,970 and place that in `B`, and the do a `git add` and `git commit` for the fresh new files. Then create a patch from `A` (using `git format-patch`) for commits #27,971 throught #28,000, and apply that patch (using `git apply`) to `B`. This all seemed to work fine, except it did not maintain the history of commits for the given files. That is, after applying the patch, it appear that all changes from all 30 commits happened at once: the history was not preserved.

There's gotta be a simple way to do this!

Comment: I can think of a number of different ways to do what you want, but I'll just answer with the first simplest one that comes off the top of my head. Also, do you basically just want to make a new repo `B` that's a clone of `A`, but only of its most recent 30 commits?

Comment: @Cupcake I edited my question: `B` has its own files; its not a new repo.

Comment: What kind of files does `B` contain, and how are they related to the files in `A`? If they're the same files but share a different history (like what you would get after a rebase), then I'm not surprised to you end up getting conflicts when you merge files from `A` into `B`. Be very careful about how you resolve those conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I looked into two possible options to do what you're looking for. One of them is to make a **shallow clone** of repo `A`, but according to [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

Not being able to do basic network options like push and fetch from a shallow repo sounds like a pretty big limitation, so I think this next option might be better for you. Instead of making a shallow repo, you could try making an ***orphan branch*** starting at commit `master~29`, then rebase commits `master~28..master` on top of it:

```bash
git checkout --orphan root master~29
git add .
git commit -m "Add your message here"
```

That will start your orphan branch off, with a new root commit that contains the state of your history at commit `master~29`. Next you'll want to rebase the descendant commits back on top (this will preserve history, except for the commit dates, which will necessarily be updated because of the rebase):

```bash
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto root master~29 master
# or `-p` for short
git rebase -p --onto root master~29 master
```

That will reconstruct the rest of `master` on top of your new root, while also preserving any merge commits. If you want to confirm that this new version of `master` is the same as the old one, just with a shorter history, then just do a diff immediately after the rebase:

```
git diff master@{1} master
```

**I highly recommend that you test this one another clone first**.

[Documentation for orphan branches](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html).

Comment: Thanks! Your orphan branch strategy worked for me. Note that I did all the above commands to repository `A`, and then I `git pull`-ed `A` into `B`. There were a few merge conflicts to take care of for some reason, but nothing I couldn't handle.